# Colorizing polar plot by clusters

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates

I have a polar plot (see below). I want to colorize the plot by cluster of points (about 0 deg, 60 deg, 90 deg 180 deg, 270 deg and 330 deg). I have tried to find some sort of function but could not. Is there a way in which this can be accomplished?

[image: polar plot of mean of residuals vs azimuth angle]

Edit: polar plot produced using command

polar(azi*pi/180,mean_res,'.');

Comment: and some data perhaps ...

Comment: data and code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hold on` with `polar` to plot in different colours:

How to split your data into the four parts depends on your (not posted) data.

```
% Example data (MathWorks)
theta1 = 0:0.01:pi;
theta2 = pi:0.01:2*pi;
rho1 = sin(2*theta1).*cos(2*theta1);
rho2 = sin(2*theta2).*cos(2*theta2);

% Plot
figure
polar(theta1,rho1,'r*');
hold on;
polar(theta2,rho2,'b*');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to sort the data into subsets based on your range criteria and plot them individually on the same plot (using the "hold" function).

You can't add the color property directly in the polar function, so you need to capture the plot handle and modify it after plotting like this:

```
hp = polar(theta,rho,'.');
hold on
set(hp,'Color',[1 0 0]);
hp2 = polar(theta2,rho2,'.');
set(hp2,'Color',[0 1 0]);
```

and so on.

This gives you complete control over the range of colors if you want some subtlety beyond just 'r', 'g', 'b' and the other hard-coded shorthands for colors in the plot commands.